# WiFi direct discovery in idle state

Tags: android, wifi-direct, service-discovery

I have 2 devices A and B. After installing Android open source WifiDirectDemo application in both the devices, if I don't go to discover page or open application in device A, I cannot discover/list device A in device B.

Is it possible to discover and connect to a device in idle state? I mean, without adding local service or without starting discovery process in device A. Basically without launching WiFiDirectDemo application at all in device A.

Comment: What do you mean by idle state?

Comment: idle state means without adding local service or without starting discovery process. Basically without launching WiFiDirectDemo application at all in device A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the answer is No. Basically you can only see active WiFi Direct Peers with peer discovery, i.e. the peer must be either connected, or doing peer discovery in order to be visible to the other devices discovery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I experienced it while playing with WifiDirectDemo app but I needed strong proof of non possibility. Even Android developer site does not mention anything about that.